# Modify build path of assets in Vite/Rollup?

Tags: javascript, rollup, vite

Let's say I have this folder structure:

```
parent
|-parent.html
|-parent.js
|-child
|--child.html
|--child.js
```

I want them to output in the same structure in my dist folder.
By default this is what gets output:

```
dist/assets/parent.js
dist/assets/child.js
```

I want them to output like this:

```
dist/parent/parent.js
dist/parent/child/child.js
```

I tried changing the `assetFileNames` option of Rollup but it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output filenames are configured in Rollup with [`build.rollupOptions`](https://vitejs.dev/config/#build-rollupoptions). Set [`output.entryFileNames`](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputentryfilenames) to configure the location of the entry `.js` files to match their original directory structure:

```js
// vite.config.js
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import path from 'path';

const rootDir = fileURLToPath(new URL('.', import.meta.url));

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        parent: './parent/parent.html',
        child: './parent/child/child.html',
      },
      output: {
        entryFileNames: (assetInfo) => {
          // assetInfo.facadeModuleId contains the file's full path
          if (assetInfo.facadeModuleId) {
            const assetPath = path.dirname(assetInfo.facadeModuleId).replace(rootDir, '');
            return assetPath + '/[name]-[hash].js';

          } else {
            return 'assets/js/[name]-[hash].js';
          }
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-output-file-paths-1amrwa?file=vite.config.js)

##### Notes

- Assets (such as `.css` files) and shared modules (vendor `.js` chunks) cannot be redirected with the solution above because the asset info from the related hooks do not provide the file's full path.
- In a vanilla Rollup project, [`output.preserveModules=true`](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputpreservemodules) would've accomplished the original goal, but that option conflicts with Vite's own settings for Rollup.

Comment: Thanks, got it working. Just need to make sure the first character isn't '/' or it throws an error.